# TypeInitializationException and NullReferenceException in Gallio when calling a shared member of a class

Tags: .net, vb.net, nullreferenceexception, typeinitializeexception

I'm trying to use Gallio and MbUnit (version 3.2.750).

As per the tutorial ( http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=getting_started:my_first_tests ), I created a new class project, referenced the other project I wanted to test (another class library), wrote a few tests, then ran them.

Every single one of my tests are really, really simple. And the methods I test are also simple.

Here is an example. The tested function :

```
    Public Shared Function IsBool(ByVal data As Object) As Boolean
        Dim retour As Boolean = True
        Try
            If data.ToString IsNot Nothing Then
                If data.ToString = "1" Or data.ToString = "0" Then
                    retour = True
                Else
                    Boolean.Parse(data.ToString)
                End If

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            retour = False
        End Try

        Return retour
    End Function
```

And the test :

```
    <Test()> _
    Public Sub IsBool_trueString()
        Dim result As Boolean = IsBool("true")
        Assert.AreEqual(True, result)
    End Sub
```

And the error :

```
System.TypeInitializationException: Une exception a été levée par l'initialiseur de type pour 'CMS.Utility'. ---> System.NullReferenceException: La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet.
   à CMS.Utility..cctor() dans C:\...\Utility.vb:ligne 12
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
TypeName: CMS.Utility
   à CMS.Utility.IsBool(Object data)
   à KoamaOPTests.CMS.Tests.Utility.IsBool_trueString() dans C:\...\Tests\Utility.vb:ligne 34
```

I realise there should be no such exception with a shared method, which is why it has me very, very confused.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your static/shared method `IsBool` is part of the class `CMS.Utility` which has most probably a [static constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (around line 12 in *Utility.vb*).

Static constructors are called once before the type can be used for the first time *(that is before `IsBool` is even executed)*. It seems that there is bug in it which causes a null reference exception. Can you post the code of the method near the line 12?

Comment: Line 12 is this : Public Shared ReadOnly conn As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ToString). I'll try to change it to a singleton property. Thanks !